# PHP goto control structure infinite execution

Tags: php, goto, control-structure

This seems to execute like an infinite loop.

```
a:
    echo "Statement 1 \n";
b:
    echo "Statement 2 \n";
if(1 > 2)
    goto a;
else
    goto b;
```

But this works correctly.

```
if(1 > 2)
    goto a;
else
    goto b;
a:
    echo "Statement 1 \n";
b:
    echo "Statement 2 \n";
```

What makes the difference.How can i execute some block of code again like in the first case.Example

```
$b = 1;
$c = 2;
$a = $b+$c;

if($a > $ b)
  // here i want to cal $a = $b+$c; without using function or copy pasting the code.
```

Comment: "some block of code" --- define "some block".

Comment: You should probably avoid using GOTOs if you can, and if you can't, you may be doing something wrong. Why not just use a function instead?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a function? Also a will always be greater than b in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an infinite loop because... your code is an infinite loop!

```
    a:
        echo "...";
.-- b: <------------.
|       echo "..."; |
|   if(1 > 2)       |
|       goto a;     |
|   else            |
`-----> goto b; ----´
```

It will output:

```
Statement 1
Statement 2
Statement 2
Statement 2
Statement 2
[...]
```

Named sections of code (`a:` and `b:`) do not stop the script; they are just names that you can jump to. Named sections of code will always be executed if reached.

Answer (score 2):

goto will jump to that part of the code. So in the first case you jump up and start again at b: and then you do that over and over again. But in the second case you jump down.

Comment: It doesn't just execute that first line under your `b:` label. As WizKid says, it **jumps** and continues on with all the code after, thus giving you your infinite loop